# TypeError: onSelect() is not a function in ReactJS, using functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-cdn-m2xxn).

I'm trying to store a value in my state and every time the user goes to the previous step he can see what he has selected and after that he can change and move on to the next step.

At the first step, everything works good. For example, the user selects the second text and proceeds to the next step, and when he returns to this step, he sees that the second text has already been selected...

The problem is with the second step, I write all the same, but it doesn't work for the second step.

The error says onSelect is not a function in `src/component/SelectCard.js`. Please help me solve this problem.

Here is my code.

App file

```
 export default function App() {
     const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
     const [term, setTerm] = useState(1);

     const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

     const [data, setData] = useState({
       firstName: "bob",
       lastName: "Forest",
       age: 47
     });
      const steps = [
        {
          title: "Package Choose",
          content: (
            <PackageChoose
              setCurrent={setCurrent}
              data={data}
              setData={setData}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
         ),
          id: 0
        },
        {
          title: "Term",
          content: (
            <Term
              setCurrent={setCurrent}
              data={data}
              selected={term}
              setSelected={setTerm}
            />
          ),
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: "Last step",
          content: <LastStep setCurrent={setCurrent} data={data} />,
          id: 2
        }
      ];
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>{steps[current].content}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

first step package choose file

```
    const PackageChoose = ({
      setCurrent,
      data,
      setData,
      setSelected,
      selected
    }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, packageType: "choice" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={1}
              selected={selected}
              onSelect={setSelected}
              text="text 1"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, packageType: "select" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={2}
              selected={selected}
              onSelect={setSelected}
              text="text 2"
             />
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrent(1)}>Next</button>
        </div>
      );
   };
```

second step Term file

```
   const Term = ({ setCurrent, data, setData, term, setTerm }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrent(0)}>Prev</button>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, termType: "30 day" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={1}
              selected={term}
              onSelect={setTerm}
              text=" term text 1"
            />
         </div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, termType: "90 day" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={2}
              selected={term}
              onSelect={setTerm}
              text="term text 2"
            />
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrent(2)}>Next</button>
            </div>
      );
    };
```

SelectCard file , in this file I am using onSelect

```
   const SelectCard = ({ id, selected, onSelect, text }) => {
      const myClassName =
        id === selected
          ? Styles.selectCardWrapperActives
          : Styles.selectCardWrapper;

      return (
        <div className={classNames(myClassName)} onClick={() => onSelect(id)}>
          <div> {text} </div>
        </div>
      );
     };
```

Please help me to understand how can I fix this problem in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Please look.

Your issue in props that you passed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-leftpad-3owuu

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the following to Term.jsx:

```
    <Term
      setCurrent={setCurrent}
      data={data}
      selected={term}
      setSelected={setTerm}
    />
```

but then in Term you get:

```
const Term = ({ setCurrent, data, setData, term, setTerm }) => {
```

setTerm is undefined because you pass it under the name setSelected. So change App.jsx as such:

```
    <Term
      setCurrent={setCurrent}
      data={data}
      selected={term}
      setTerm={setTerm}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, it help to avoid that problem, but still I can't select nothing in `Term.js`. Can you look ?... I changed as you says.
 In `package Choose.js` when I am clicking on one of the div's one of them was selected, but it not works for `term.js` file 
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-wave-fg3rn

Comment: again you have term as a props you need and you don't pass this props to <Terms />